# Include an object defined outside Angular ecosystem into a factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs

We're having an argument, which I hope you guys will help resolve.

Say I have a simple factory defined like this:

```
angular.module('myModule', [])

.factory('Fact', function() {
    var Fact = function() {
        var that = {};

        that.var1 = [];
        that.var2 = [];

        return that;
    };

    var fact = {
        get: function() {
            return Fact();
        }
    };

    return fact;
});
```

I found out that this code will be working if I write it like this:

```
angular.module('myModule', [])

.factory('Fact', function() {
    var fact = {
        get: function() {
            return Fact();
        }
    };

    return fact;
});


var Fact = function() {
    var that = {};

    that.var1 = [];
    that.var2 = [];

    return that;
};
```

Namely, I can take this code of the object `Fact` and put it in some other plain `.js` file, include it before the Angular one (in `index.html` file) and this "would work".

However, I'm trying to resolve an argument that this approach is not good (well, not an Angular approach at that) because then this `Fact` is "laying around on the global scope", which is not good.

In which circumstances would you say that this is/isn't a good solution?

Is there a way to include a "nonAngular" code (simple JavaScript code written in some `.js` file) into the Angular factory?

Comment: I use a global: var vendor = {} and I put all external functions inside this variable. And after, I use on angular modules... but I have only 2 or 3 functions with this need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Between factories, services, providers, constants and values, there's not really a good reason to have any code outside of Angular's constructs **unless** it's third party code.

If it is, you won't have control over the way that the library, framework, etc registers itself. It might use the global scope, alternatively, it might provide a module export.

Where possible, the cleanest and safest way to include third party code inside Angular is with a build-step using a module bundler.

For instance, I want to use the hypothetical package `foojs` from inside Angular using [browserify](http://browserify.org/):

Install the package with npm

```
npm install --save foojs
```

Then use it like this.

```
var foojs = require('foojs');

var app = angular.app('myapp')

app.service('myservice', function() {
  // here we can use foojs safely
});
```

You can also achieve similar things with [WebPack](https://webpack.github.io).

The reason this is safer is because after the build step, all the modules will be wrapped inside a function that protects the global scope.

If you aren't able to use a module bundler, then the only option is to use the global scope and allow the third party code to bind onto the window object.